# Use same script in multiple jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, filter

I am unable use the same script into two places with another div.below the I need to use the same one into two different type of filters. I copied the same one and changed classname but still not working.

[codepen](https://codepen.io/terf/pen/vGeqC)

[live website](http://mobilegear.my/alphatiles/alphatile/view/600mm--x--600mm)

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var $btns = $('.prdsiz-filter .button-group .btn').click(function() {
      if (this.id == 'all') {
        $('.prosize-sec > .inner-sectn').fadeIn(450);
      } else {
        var $el = $('.' + this.id).fadeIn(450);
        $('.prosize-sec > .inner-sectn').not($el).hide();
      }
      $btns.removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
    });
    });
    $( document ).ready(function() {
    var $btnsm = $('.promob-filter .mobbtn-group .btn').click(function() {
      if (this.id == 'showall') {
        $('.promob-sec > .mobinner-sectn').fadeIn(450);
      } else {
        var $elm = $('.' + this.id).fadeIn(450);
        $('.promob-sec > .mobinner-sectn').not($elm).hide();
      }
      $btnsm.removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});
```

Comment: Why dont you just write a function? You can call it as many times as you want, into as many filters as you like

Comment: I don't know what you asking about?

Comment: I didn't understand what you want but in the second script you are removing the class from $btns it should be $btns1

Comment: now you check I updated the script

Comment: I took a look to you website, and is think you have just messed up you class names. Your code is correct in general.

Comment: any solution? . Did you found the mistake?

Comment: What is your question / Issue ?

Comment: found answer. Thx all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can achieve using this. Have to use different id instead of class name.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
var $btns = $('.prdsiz-filter #button-group .btn').click(function() {
  if (this.id == 'all') {
    $('.prosize-sec > .inner-sectn').fadeIn(450);
  } else {
    var $el = $('.' + this.id).fadeIn(450);
    $('.prosize-sec > .inner-sectn').not($el).hide();
  }
  $btns.removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
});
$( document ).ready(function() {
var $btnsm = $('.promob-filter #mobbtn-group .btn').click(function() {
  if (this.id == 'showall') {
    $('.promob-sec > .inner-sectn').fadeIn(450);
  } else {
    var $elm = $('.' + this.id).fadeIn(450);
    $('.promob-sec > .inner-sectn').not($elm).hide();
  }
  $btnsm.removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

});